# Kingston Fury Renegade compatibility with AMD B550 chipset?

Tags: memory, compatibility

I am considering to buy one of two modules **Kingston HyperX Fury HX436C18FB3/32** or **Kingston Fury Renegade Black KF432C16RB/32**. Both should not have big performance differences, I guess, but Renegade is newer RAM. So there is compatibility question.

My motherboard is Gigabyte B550M DS3H and processor AMD Ryzen 3900X.

Do you know of any compatibility issues that might happed with this new Renegade Black module or I need nothing to worry about compatibility here? Cause I might buy HyperX instead, I know that this module worked and is listed in Gigabyte's **memory compatibility list**, but there are no Renegade listed.

Thank you.

Comment: The motherboard manufacturers hardly ever update those memory compatibility lists; They test a few dozen common products when they make the motherboard and don't look back. However, that list is really only a suggestion. There are **tons** of DDR4 sticks to pick from and theoretically speaking all of them should be compatible because they all have to match the DDR4 standard. There is always a chance that even a "compatible" stick isn't working as intended and would cause the same problems anyway. So... just buy any RAM and make sure there's a return policy in case you need it.

Answer (score 1):

My RAM is also not on the motherboard compatibility list (B450 + Ryzen 3 3100) and it works (really well, I overclocked it). So you can take a small risk and buy the faster RAM, or take no risk and buy the slower ram. Its your choice if the risk is worth it. (the hyperx is like <2% slower so I won't take the risk)

Comment: Hello, it's more about pricing than performance. I can maybe buy this modules a 20 EUR less per module.

Comment: The renegade or the hyperx?

Comment: It's renegade module.

Comment: Its a risk in terms of compatibility, and if you are willing to take the risk, you can buy the renegade. Because its also cheaper, I would then take the risk